# ASP.NET Identity and Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I am using ASP.NET Identity and Unity in a project to implement DI.
there is something wrong with signInManager. I can't use it in constructor because it has error. please help me. UserManager and RoleManager are working properly. but how can I use signInManager as interface.

this is my AuthersController :

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

    public AuthorsController(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userManager, IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleManager, IAuthenticationManager signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userManager);
        _roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleManager);
        _signInManager = new SignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>(signInManager);
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }
```

and this is my UnityConfig :

```
        var Constructor = new InjectionConstructor(new ApplicationDbContext());
        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(Constructor);
        container.RegisterType<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>, RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>>(Constructor);

        // TODO: Register your types here
        container.RegisterType<IPostsRepository, PostsService>();
        container.RegisterType<ICategoriesRepository, CategoriesService>();
        container.RegisterType<ITagsRepository, TagsService>();
```

Comment: you should really show the error but is it due to the `signInManager` definition: `ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager` and `_signInManager = new SignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>(signInManager)`?

Comment: and now it says : Using the generic type 'SignInManager<TUser, TKey>' requires 2 type arguments @qujck

Comment: Related: [AspNet Identity and IoC Container Registration](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
```

Comment: @Hatef can you accept this answer, or you need  another solution?